# visual studio 2012 fails to monitor memory?

Tags: .net

I got a Windows 7 OS, Project is 32Bits running on 64 Bits architecture, .Net 4.5
IDE : Visual Studio 2012
App : A console app.

I want to monitor the memory usage of my exe.

I go to Analyse/Start Memory and get an  error message : 
Variable environment are not set, I must run VSPerfCLREnv /samplegclife to set correct env variables. I naievely thought that Visual Studio wuld call the exe to set the vars, why asking me to do this ?

I am not launching from a shell window, where I would set the vars, start the analyze then launch my exe and finally stop the profiler. 
I am inside the IDE, this should be done by the tool.

By the way, analyzing UC works ok, without calling VSPerfCLREnv.

What is wrong here ?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Under the principal of ["Do one thing and do it well"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) VS can't do _everything_. It does integrate with a lot of things, but for the same reason you have the Expression suite for UI things, VSPerf is there for profiling and is an external tool (though I agree with you, it should be married a bit better). [footnote: Citing a Unix adage in a windows post--irony anyone?]

Comment: I agree that the tool can't do everything BUT when I Google for the usage of the menu, It SHOULD work as is. I am not supposed to use the CLI tools.